# How do I rig a skeleton to another model? I want to make a mod

Tags: modeling, rigging

[image]

I have imported the Cavalry night set from Elden ring into Blender as an FBX. I have imported the Aknosom armor from Monster hunter rise into Blender as an RE mesh.

*I want to make a Monster hunter rise mod that replaces the Aknosom armor with the Cavalry night armor from Elden ring.*

I don't know how to proceed from here. My understanding is I am supposed to rig the skeletons together.

Please provide advice on what to do step by step.